# Route ICECAST stream to alsa dummy device

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, alsa, pulse-audio

I want to transmit an icecast stream to udp via FFmpeg, but if the icecast stream will be dropped then FFmpeg drops also. I suppose if I could route the icecast stream to alsa dummy device then I could get data from it via FFmpeg. For example:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:Dummy,0 -f mpegts udp://ip:port
```

Then in case of icecast stream dropping, the output udp stream will be played silently and continue playing audio until this stream is available again. (This is my assumption).

**Is there a way to route icecast stream to alsa dummy device?** Or is there another variant for routing icecast stream to udp to play silently in case of icecast stream dropout, and then automatically return to normal playing when the icecast stream is available again?

Comment: You tagged this question with pulseaudio. Does it have to be an ALSA dummy device, or can it also be a Pulseaudio source? Much easier to set up (though I am not sure about the start/stop behaviour, would have to find out that).

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for the comment! It's an ALSA dummy device. I tagged the question with pulseaudio, because as I understood we can use pulseaudio to route an icecast stream to dummy ALSA device. But I can be wrong) In any case I want to create a virtual sound device -> route an icecast stream to it -> get this stream from the virtual sound device via ffmpeg. Any solution will be appropriate, without any mandatory conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your comment as "using Pulseaudio to do it is ok". I haven't tested this, but here's what I'd do:

First, create a Pulseaudio "null" sink:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=icecast sink_properties=device.description=Icecast
```

In Pulseaudio, each sink has an associated `.monitor` source, so in this way you can output sound to the `icecast` sink, and process in other applications using the `icecast.monitor` source.

If I understand you correctly, you want to *receive* the icecast stream on your computer. To output the stream to the `icecast` sink, do something like

```
mplayer http://your.icecast.server -ao pulse::icecast
```

When the icecast stream ends, `mplayer` will also terminate, so wrap that in a shell script inside an infinite `while` loop etc.

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do with the "stream to udp via ffmpeg" part. In any case, you can now read from `icecast.monitor` with

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse ...
```

while using `pavucontrol` or `pamcd` to select the right source, or, if your `ffmpeg` is compile with pulseaudio support, directly

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i icecast.monitor ...
```

However, if the idea is "I want to distribute that icecast stream to other computers in my home network", it may be better to use a [Pulseaudio RTP module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2) as the sink in the first place.

As I said, none of this is tested, you may have to adjust parts to make it work.

**Edit**

I'm also not sure an ALSA dummy device would work in the first place, to my understanding they are really just "dummy" devices and don't provide loopback. You'd have to use the `snd-aloop` loopback device for that, and this one is a bit of a pain, because you constantly run into sampling rate issues etc.

So you're really better off using the Pulseaudio infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked and it works great! Silent when icecast stream is down and playing without any errors when it running again! UDP output is stable!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Loopback device instead of the Dummy device.

The Loopback device is not enabled by default, so you must first load the snd-aloop kernel module with arguments to specify the desired type and number of substreams:

```
# modprobe snd-aloop index=0 pcm_substreams=1
```

Then instead of routing icecast to `hw:Dummy,0`, you can route it to `hw:Loopback,0,0` and read that stream in ffmpeg from `hw:Loopback,1,0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain how to route an icecast stream to alsa loopback device?

Comment: @IvanKolesnikov That should be achievable with any player capable of streaming from IceCast, as long as you play to the device hw:Loopback,0,0

For example, with MPV you would do `mpv --audio-device=alsa/hw:Loopback,0,0 http://example.com/path/to/icecast/stream` or with SoX, you would do `sox http://example.com/path/to/icecast/stream -t alsa hw:Loopback,1,0`.